# Why we need trigger to delete from View?

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql, triggers

Sometimes I found some code that makes triggers to allow user to delete from View ?
But why we need to delete from View ,, because simply we can Go to Table > and execute delete like  this simple code :

```
delete from table where x=y ;
```

My question why we use deletion on views by using TRIGGERS ؟ 
in another words what is the advantages of using delete over a View !

Answer (score 2):

> The reason we use view are mainly to hide the complexity of data
>   sources , Hide away the actual tables (For security reasons), saving
>   us writing the same code over and over again.
>
> Now if you havent let your users access the tables directly and they
>   only work through View in this case they will be executing `Deletes`
>   against views.
>
> Triggers are only used when your View has more than One underlying
>   table. You cannot do update, insert or delete operations on view if it
>   effects multiple underlying tables. Therefore we make use of `Instead
>   of Delete/Update/Insert Triggers` to do these operations against
>   views.
>
> When you have multiple Underlying tables if you Update,Delete or
>   Insert effects only One underlying table it does allow you to execute
>   the statement but it is not guaranteed that it will be done correctly.
>
> therefore if you have a situation where your view is based on
>   multiple underlying tables you should always do update/delete/inserts
>
> 1) Directly to underlying tables. 
>  2) Use Instead of triggers.

Also <kbd>[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497808/how-can-i-perform-dml-operations-in-sql-server/21497940#21497940)</kbd> for more details on why you shouldnt do update/delete/insert operations on views with multiple underlying tables.